# On watson conversation panel how to set the intent right on the respond json?

Tags: json, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

i am building a conversation on the watson conversaton, and in a point, togeter with my "response" json, i woul also link to set a new intent for the user, i tried to add this to the json, but with no result.

There is a way to do this?

[image: watson screen]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [Official documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-runtime.html#context), you can use `context variables` for save values.

> A context variable is a variable that you define in a node, and
>   optionally specify a default value for. Other nodes or application
>   logic can subsequently set or change the value of the context
>   variable.

So, in this case, you'll create in your JSON advance (like your example) something like:

```
{
  "context": {
    "intent": "fgts",
    "confidence": 1
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Your text here"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

And in your back-end application, you can access the value in the response JSON object from your POST /message, with something like: `response.context.intent` and `response.context.confidence`

**Obs.:** By *default*, Watson Conversation service will return the name of the `intent` that Watson recognizes and the `confidence` level.

*If really after these instructions you want to use your method. You can see my example below:*

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "text here"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    },
    "intents": "test"
  }
}
```

And your app return:

```
{ intents: [ { intent: 'helpBot', confidence: 0.5930036529133407 } ],
  entities: [],
  input: { text: 'ajuda' },
  output:
   { text: [ 'text here' ],
     nodes_visited: [ 'node_16_1511443279233' ],
     intents: 'test',
     log_messages: [] },
  context:
   { conversation_id: '83d88b05-7c76-457d-bd5f-7820be455a3e',
     system:
      { dialog_stack: [Object],
        dialog_turn_counter: 2,
        dialog_request_counter: 2,
        _node_output_map: [Object],
        branch_exited: true,
        branch_exited_reason: 'fallback' } } }
```

- See more about [accessing values using Conversation Service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#shorthand-syntax-for-context-variables).

Comment: ok, i knew that i could use context variables, but my answer is other, i want to SET the intent right there through the json... (#intent)